# Can't find app with name error while publish the azure function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-core-tools

I tried to create an azure function using following link in Ubuntu system(16.04).
[azure function][2]

Deployment using arm template and create a local azure function using vs code.
Folder contains following files

> LocalFunctionProj.csproj, HttpExample.cs, host.json, local.settings.json

azure function is created successfully in portal after deployment.But when i tried to publish the local azure function ,it shows an error **Can't find app with name "HttpExample"** while using following command

```
func azure functionapp publish HttpExample
```

Is anything wrong in my step.

Also i tried this command after 30 mnt when function created in portal

[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lb3rL.png)

Comment: what is the name of the function app

Comment: in locally HttpExample is name.this is the name in the example

Comment: try removing the . after HttpEcample

Comment: sorry no dots in actual commands. thats not the problem

Comment: do the arm template contains app name and local  function name should be the same ?

Comment: definitely it needs to be the same

Comment: you mean the name in local and cloud app should be same right?.Suppose If i have two resource group in portal with azure function have same name ,how the publish command distinguish it ?

Comment: Hi, I don't think it's necessary the name of local function and cloud function should be same. Please make sure you login with the azure account by the command `az login` as mentioned in the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-function-resource-manager?tabs=command-line%2Cpowershell#validate-the-deployment) you provided. Also please check if you login to the correct tenant if you have multiple tenants(use `az login --tenant <tenant>`).

Comment: @FrankGong.
i did the same way. az login --tenant <tenant>. Suppose if i have two resource group with two different azure function. How do i identify the function while i publish my local azure function?

Comment: Do you mean you have already solved the deployment problem by `az login --tenant <tenant>`?

Comment: And i'm not clear about your new question, when you publish the function from local to azure by command, we just need to specify the function name in the command. So i do not understand why did you concern about the resource group.

Comment: @FrankGong.Problem not solved.i did the way as same as you mentioned

Comment: you can't create the two app with same name in a same portal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to publish the local app into azure ,you must create the functional app before in azure portal.Also the name of the azure function is portal should be same as the local azure app.otherwise you can't publish the app.

Comment: could you please elaborate more

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue when I followed a [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/develop-test-deploy-azure-functions-with-core-tools/5-exercise-publish-function-core-tools) about Azure Functions Core Tools from Microsoft Learning.

In my case, I had the error `Can't find app with name X`, because I had a wrong subscription set in my local Azure CLI. The command from below changes subscription for the one that is created with "Microsoft Learning Sandbox". Note that, in your case, the name of the subscription can be different.

```
az account set --subscription "Concierge Subscription"
```

If it's not the issue, your question suggests that your function app name should be `HttpExample`. You need to ensure beforehand that there's a function app with such a name in the subscription you are logged into with Azure CLI.

Moreover, there is a `ProvisioningState: Failed` in the screenshot, which could also be an issue.